# How do you implement a trait for T where T: Foo OR Bar

Tags: generics, rust, traits, trait-objects

In rust, you can automatically implement a trait for any type that implements some other combination of traits. Ie:

```rust
impl<T: Foo + Bar> SomeTrait for T {
    some_function(&self) {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is define a relationship where `Foo` and `Bar` are *both* enough to implement `SomeTrait` by themselves. Basically, something like this:

```rust
impl<T: Foo> SomeTrait for T {
    some_function(&self) {
        /*...*/
    }
}

impl<T: Bar> SomeTrait for T {
    some_function(&self) {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

This won't compile, because you're implementing `SomeTrait` for `T` twice and the compiler can't possibly know what to do in the case where `T: Foo + Bar`, but it'd be really nice to be able to do this.

Is there some way to "abstract" around this problem so that I can call `some_function()` on a `T` that implements `Foo` OR `Bar`? Or am I stuck with having to pick only one implementation?

Comment: FWIW, https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42721

Comment: On stable, no. On nightly, perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

If you use nightly, you can use the [`marker_trait_attr`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29864) feature. It allows you to have overlapping impls for a trait that has the attribute `#[marker]`. Note that the trait should have no associated items - it must be empty.

Thus, you can define a marker trait `FooOrBar` (I made it in a private module so it's sealed and people cannot implement it manually):

```rust
#![feature(marker_trait_attr)]

mod private {
    #[marker]
    pub trait FooOrBar {}
    impl<T: super::Foo> FooOrBar for T {}
    impl<T: super::Bar> FooOrBar for T {}
}
```

And then implement the trait `SomeTrait` for any type that implements `FooOrBar`:

```rust
impl<T: private::FooOrBar> SomeTrait for T {
    fn foo(&self) { /* ... */ }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=adb573447cac06d80b46011585751509).

For stable, unfortunately, I don't think there is a way but a redesign.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there are some safety properties that need some serious thought before this can be a feature.

The only real way to get close to what I was after is using the [specialisation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) feature, which is unstable for a number of reasons that are a bit beyond me.

Unfortunately, this does seem to mean that traits aren't *quite* as powerful as I originally thought, but there should always be other ways to approach this kind of scenario.